# How to refresh the class properties in entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, refresh

We are using the Entity Framework Reposittory pattern.In that if i am manually added the record in database immediately the changes are not reflecting in UI.So that by using "Refresh" method refreshing the entities in Repository class.But my question is in my code i am writing the class and return the results as class properties.It's not calling any method in Repository.So that updated changes not reflecting in UI.Please tell me how to refresh the class properties (results) ?

In one of my view displayig the getusers results.But not getting latest results.We should refresh it.please tell me how to refresh users table?

EDIT :
Users.cs

```
 public Collection<Users> getusers        {
            get
            {
                return Users.Select(r => r.user).ToCollection();
            }
        }
Repository.cs
 public T SingleResult(Func<T, bool> expression)
        {
            m_context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins,m_table);
            return m_table.FirstOrDefault(expression);
        }
```

EDIT :

```
finalList = (from e in m_context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                                                EntityState.Added
                                                | EntityState.Deleted
                                                | EntityState.Modified
                                                | EntityState.Unchanged)

                         where e.EntityKey != null
                         select e.Entity).ToList();
            m_context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, finalList);
```

The above code GetObjectStateEntries() not returning the manually updated changes ?i am trying to add the new record in Db that record not reflcting immediatley in ui.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't be answered without seeing code.

Comment: check my edit changes ?

Comment: @Gert Arnold please check my code and could please tell me solution for this?

Comment: How have you implemented Users (as in Users.Select(r => r.user).ToCollection();) could you please share that code with us

Comment: is it possible to refresh the whole context instead of single object entity?i need to get manually updated changes in DB ,immediatley not refelcting in UI?please check my edit code.